# Display values of a column using other columns

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 columns, registered, and overall. The text in the overall column is determined by testing out the other column.

I have this in the table property validation rule.

```
iif([registered] = false, [overall] = "T", [overall] = "F")
```

When i run this the overall column is still empty, I have to enter the correct text (T or F) manually. It there a way to automatically fill in the column?

Comment: iif(Cbool([registered]) = False, [overall] = "T", [overall] = "F"). This should do it.

Comment: it still doesn't show up automatically. I have to enter it manually

Comment: What datatype does overall has in your table?

Comment: You must update the registered column in order to see values in overall column.

Comment: i did, it still didn't work

Comment: Did you try using an update query to directly push the data in overall column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Validation Rule defines what data values can be stored.  However, a Validation Rule can not *alter* the values which are stored.  So you need something else.

Based on your description, I'm unsure why `[overall]` must be a table field.  You could make it a field expression in a query instead.

```sql
SELECT
    registered,
    IIf([registered] = False, "T",  "F") AS overall
FROM YourTable;
```

Use the query anywhere you need to see `[overall]`.

If you need `[overall]` to be an actual table field, and if your Access version is >= 2010 and if you can use the ACCDB database format, `[overall]` could be a [calculated field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-HA101820564.aspx).  However, that would mean your database could only be used by Access >=2010, or from other applications using a suitable version of the ACE driver.

Answer (score 0):

Set de datasource for overall field as:

```
=iif([registered] = false, "T", "F")
```

If you need to store the overall field in database. Handle the AfterUpdate event for Registered:

```
Sub Registered_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Overall = Iif([registered] = false, "T", "F")
End Sub
```